# Trigonometric bearings

Tags: trigonometry

A and B are 2 points on level ground, and B is a metres due east of A; a tower, h metres high , is also on the same level ground. From A the tower is in a direction of N θ E and from B it is N $\phi$ W.  From the top of the tower, the angle of depression of A is α and of B it is β. 
Prove:

$(i) h\sin(\theta + \phi) = a\cos\phi\ \tan\alpha
\\(ii) cos\phi \tan\alpha = cos\theta\tan\beta
\\(iii)h^2(\cot^2\alpha - \cot^2\beta) - 2ha\cot\alpha\sin\theta + a^2 = 0$

I have managed (i) and (ii) but am at a loss as regard (iii)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iii) Apply the cosine rule to the triangle ABP

$$BP^2=AP^2+a^2-2aAP\cos(90-\theta)$$

Note that $AP = h\cot \alpha$ and $BP = h\cot \beta$. Plug them into the cosine equation above to get

$$h^2(\cot^2 \alpha -  \cot^2\beta )- 2ha\cot\alpha\sin\theta + a^2 =0$$